# PHP function issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

Trying to generate db driven menu which based on parent->child structure. All root menu items' parent column values are 0. Getting following errors continuously

```
Undefined offset: 0,1,2 on line list($id, $parent, $name) = $results; 

 Undefined index on line  array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given on line   if (!array_key_exists($tree[$parent]['children'][$id])) {

Warning: array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given on line   if (!array_key_exists($tree[$parent]['children'][$id])) {
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

function generateMenu($parent, $level, $menu, $utype) {
    global $db;
    $tree = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select id, parent, name FROM navigation WHERE menu=? AND user_type=?") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $menu, $utype) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $bindResult = array();
    while ($columnName = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $bindResult[] = &$results[$columnName->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $bindResult);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        list($id, $parent, $name) = $results;
        $tree[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'children' => array(), 'parent' => $parent);
        if (!array_key_exists($id, $tree[$parent]['children'])) {
            $tree[$parent]['children'][$id] = $id;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    print_r($tree);
}

?>
```

**And DB structure**

[image]

**For testing purposes**

- Tried   `die(print_r($results));` right after  `while
  ($stmt->fetch()) {`. Getting first row of my db table as `Array (
  [id] => 1 [parent] => 0 [name] => Sual ) 1`.
- Tried   `while ($results=$stmt->fetch()) {` instead of `while ($stmt->fetch()) {`. Got following errors again

  Undefined index on line  array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given on line   if (!array_key_exists($tree[$parent]['children'][$id])) {

  Warning: array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given on line   if (!array_key_exists($tree[$parent]['children'][$id])) {
- Tried   `if (!array_key_exists($id, $tree[$parent]['children'])) {` instead of `if (!array_key_exists($tree[$parent]['children'][$id])) {`. Got following errors again

  Undefined offset: 0,1,2 on line list($id, $parent, $name) = $results;

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//try echoing the list values
//Your syntax is wrong
array_key_exists($yourKey, $yourSearchArray);
```

Comment: please modify the code if it's possible. How will it look like?

Comment: tried  `print_r($results);` right after `list($id, $parent, $name) = $results;` it echoed all rows like that `Array ( [id] => 4 [parent] => 1 [name] => Yeni sual ) ` Yes you're right. But what I must fix? Please modify code