# Array "tree" creation from db table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, tree, hierarchical-data

My php function

```
function generateMenu($parent, $level, $menu, $utype) {
    global $db;
    $tree = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select id, parent, name FROM navigation WHERE menu=? AND user_type=?") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $menu, $utype) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $parent, $name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $arr[$id] = array(
            'name' => $name, 
            'parent' => $parent
        );
        if (!array_key_exists($parent,$arr) and $parent != 0) {
            $arr[$parent][$id] = $id;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

generates following array from db table. `[1], [2]` ... - are ids of `li` item

```
Array (
    [1] => Array ( 
        [name] => Parent1
        [parent] => 0
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [name] => Parent2
        [parent] => 0 
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [name] => Parent3 
        [parent] => 0 
    )
    [4] => Array ( 
        [name] => Child1 of P1
        [parent] => 1
    ) 
    [5] => Array (
        [name] => Child2 of P1
        [parent] => 1
    ) 
)
```

What I want to do is to create the menu like that

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="?page=1">Parent1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="?page=4">Child1 of P1</a></li>
        ...
```

Second function is for generating menu from this array. But I know that before sending this array into second function I need to convert it into multidimensional tree array. I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is second function

```
function olLiTree($tree) {
    $out = '<ul>';

    foreach($tree as $key => $value) {
        $out.= '<li>';

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $out.= $key . olLiTree($value);
        } else {
            $out.= $value;
        }

        $out.= '</li>';
    }

    $out.= '</ul>';

    return $out;
}
```

Db structure

[image: http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/4669/6df2a8e6c7684c8aaa82ddf.png]

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220517/php-function-issue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tre)

Comment: By the way, I'd go for the first answer, using recursion, and two separate functions, one to generate a multi-dimensional array (always useful) and one to generate your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) needs two parameters, you only passes one. I think you mean:

```
while(list($id, $parent, $name) = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $tree[$id] = array(
        'name' => $name, 
        'children' => array(), 
        'parent' => $parent
    );
    if (!array_key_exists($parent,$tree)) {
        $tree[$parent]['children'][$id] = $id;
    }
}
```

You changed your answer, so I think your problem are not with `array_keys_exists`. Anyway you can try with this way to obtain the data with MaxDB:

```
function generateMenu($parent, $level, $menu, $utype) {
    global $db;
    $tree = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select id, parent, name FROM navigation WHERE menu=? AND user_type=?") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $menu, $utype) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $parent, $name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $tree[$id] = array(
            'name' => $name, 
            'children' => array(), 
            'parent' => $parent
        );
        if (!array_key_exists($parent,$tree)) {
            $tree[$parent]['children'][$id] = $id;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    print_r($tree);
}
```

For your second function I think @jeroen has rigth, in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tre) is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You only passed one parameter to [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).  I think you may want to use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to see if that element exists in the array.

```
array_key_exists($id, $tree[$parent]['children']);
```

Should be roughly equivalent to:

```
isset($tree[$parent]['children'][$id]);
```

Comment: I know, but how can I modify this function to get it work, that is not my function that's why asking

Comment: Getting `Undefined offset: 0,1,2 on line list($id, $parent, $name) = $results;` errors

Answer (score 0):

I posted code to convert an array like yours into a multi-dimensional array in my answer to:

- [Convert flat array to the multi-dimentional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3261351/20860).

The tricky part is understanding PHP references.  I'm still not sure I understand them, but the code I posted is the only way it would work.

Comment: I have already taken a look at your code. There 2 problems: 1) My array structure is a bit different 2) You said "algorithm works only if parents appear up in the db result set before their children appear." Please help me to get it works. I don't understand generation of tree part